# How to forward server port from physical machine to VPN client in SoftEther?

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding, softether

In a conventional network, router would have a "NAT settings" page that we would forward some external ports to LAN devices. For example, if you have a 192.168.1.0 network and you want to expose your HTTP server on machine 192.168.1.6:4000, you would login to the router (pfSense, for example) and create a forwarding rule that practically does: "WAN:80 -> 192.168.1.6:4000".

My current status is as follows:

```
(80) WAN_IP |== HOST MACHINE ==| <----> |== SoftEther (in Host Machine) ==| <---(internet)---> (6000) |== My box: 192.168.30.17 ==|
```

I'm running an application on port 6000 on my box (192.168.30.17, connected to virtual hub: "VPN") and I want to reach the application with WAN_IP:80.

How can I perform this forwarding in SoftEther? Server is Ubuntu and I prefer the instructions for `vpncmd`, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a virtual interface between host machine and the virtual hub:

   ```
   VPN_SERVER:$ sudo ./vpncmd localhost /server /cmd BridgeCreate VPN /DEVICE:ens2 /TAP:yes
   ```
2. Check that your new virtual interface (`tap_ens2`) is created:

   ```
   VPN_SERVER:$ ifconfig | grep Ethernet
   ens2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:1a:18:12:e0:01  
   tap_ens2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5e:b4:a9:d3:82:50
   ```
3. Assign an appropriate IP to your interface:

   ```
   VPN_SERVER:$ ifconfig tap_ens2 192.168.30.5 # any available IP
   ```
4. Test that you can reach your vpn client from the host machine (assuming you started a webserver on the client on port 6000 with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 6000`):

   ```
   VPN_SERVER:$ curl 192.168.30.17:6000
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>
   <title>Directory listing for /</title>
   <body>
   <h2>Directory listing for /</h2>
   <hr>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="test.txt">test.txt</a>
   </ul>
   <hr>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
5. Create `iptables` rules (run this script on VPN_SERVER with root privileges):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   brname=tap_ens2         # the interface connected to our private lan
   braddr=192.168.30.5     # interface IP assigned externally
   iface=ens2              # the interface connected to public internet

   # Run as root.
   [[ $(whoami) = "root" ]] || { sudo $0 "$@"; exit 0; }

   # Make sure that the IP forwarding is enabled
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

   # Cleanup the iptables
   echo "Cleaning up NAT rules in iptables..."
   iptables -F -t nat

   echo "Adding forwarding rules"
   iptables -A FORWARD -i ${brname} -s ${braddr}/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE

   fwd(){
       # usage: fwd 1234 to 192.168.1.4:3000
       local ext_port=$1
       local internal=$3 # IP:Port 
       iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $iface -p tcp --dport $ext_port -j DNAT --to $internal
   }

   ## forward the desired ports
   fwd 2233 to 192.168.30.17:6000
   ```
6. Test it with your public IP:

   ```
   ANYWHERE:$ curl WAN_IP:2233
   ```